# Terraria: pre-hardmode bosses in hardmode

Tags: terraria

Can you summon pre-hardmode bosses in hardmode?

Just need to know if I should fight all pre-hardmode bosses before defeating the wall of flesh.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can summon any summonable boss in hardmode.
It may be more difficult to fight them with the hardmode mobs around, but usually, the hardmode gear will make pre-hardmode bosses die really fast.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can still summon these bosses with the same procedures as before you went into hard mode. It should be much easier, too.